# How to use overlay() in different manner in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have database like  this ,I want to overlay the field by checking in gender column and overlay in emp_name field .

```
emp_id | emp_name | gender 
-------+----------+--------
   501 | aaa      | M
   502 | bbb      | F
   503 | ccc      | F
   504 | ddd      | M
   505 | eee      | F
```

I want output like this

```
emp_id | emp_name | gender 
-------+----------+--------
   501 | Mr.aaa   | M
   502 | Ms.bbb   | F
   503 | Ms.ccc   | F
   504 | Mr.ddd   | M
   505 | Ms.eee   | F
```

I had tried the select query like this

```
$select overlay(emp_name placing 'Mr.' from 1 for 0 )  from emp where gender = 'M' ;
```

This output I got ,

```
 overlay 
---------
 Mr. aaa
 Mr. ddd
(2 rows)
```

But ,I didn't get the expected result.Is there is any way for expected result .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What result did you get?

Comment: @Eric Hauenstein,I had edited my question .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$select overlay(emp_name placing CASE gender WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mr. ' ELSE 'Ms. ' END from 1 for 0 )  from emp;
```

Not a postgresql guy, but this should work.

Answer (score 5):

The query below should give the output you expect:

```
SELECT emp_id
     , CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN 'Mr. '
            WHEN gender = 'F' THEN 'Ms. '
            ELSE '' END || emp_name as emp_name
     , gender
  FROM emp;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm strictly a TSQL guy, but try this:

```
Select CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN overlay(emp_name placing 'Mr.' from 1 for 0)
            WHEN gender = 'F' THEN overlay(emp_name placing 'Mrs.' from 1 for 0)
            END AS emp_name
 from emp
```

Comment: If you're doing a case statement, what's the point of overlay? That seems unnecessary.

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with the overlay function, so I used it as shown in the question and hoped for the best.  Your solution is clearly more concise.